# Show Spinner at the center of HTML5 Page?

Tags: html, css, spinner, uiactivityindicatorview

Hi am trying to create a simple blank html page with a spinner at center.For example something like in that image.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Find a spinner gif online- http://www.ajaxload.info or create one yourself. Then use the following code to centre it in your page:

`.spinner{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    background: url(/link/to/your/image);
    background-size: 100%;
}`